# SwiftUI: navigationDestination(item:destination:) not working on macOS

Tags: swiftui

Trying to programmatically navigate in my app, but I can't get `navigationDestination(item:destination:)` to work on macOS. It works fine on iOS, but on macOS nothing happens when clicking the button. (See ContentView1)

I also tried using `navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)` which works without a problem on both iOS and macOS. (See ContentView2). Worst case I could use this but it would require two states instead of one, which should not be necessary.

What am I doing wrong?

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    @State var text: String?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Subview") {
                text = "Subview"
            }
            .navigationDestination(item: $text) { text in       // DOES NOT WORK ON MACOS
                Text(text)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView2: View {
    @State var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Subview") {
                isPresented = true
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isPresented) {     // WORKS ON MACOS
                Text("Subview")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, too. On MacOS 14.1.2.

Comment: Same problem. macOS Sonoma 14.3.1, Xcode 15.2.